# How can I fix a fatal error in my WordPress theme caused by undefined function tonda_core_is_theme_registered()?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, themes

i'm having this problem with my theme suddenly, and it's causing my site to have a fatal error. how do i fix this:

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 8 of the file /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-content/themes/tonda/framework/modules/blog/shortcodes/shortcodes-functions.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function tonda_core_is_theme_registered() in /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-content/themes/tonda/framework/modules/blog/shortcodes/shortcodes-functions.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-content/themes/tonda/framework/modules/blog/load.php(4): include_once()
#1 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-content/themes/tonda/framework/modules/qodef-modules-loader.php(12): include_once('/home4/mojsoapc...')
#2 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): tonda_select_load_modules('')
#3 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-content/themes/tonda/framework/admin/options/qodef-options-setup.php(5): do_action('tonda_select_ac...')
#6 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): tonda_select_admin_map_init('')
#7 /home4/mojsoapc/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp

i tried restoring a backup which didn't work, deleting and reuploading the theme didn't work, and hiding the line as a comment also didn't work.

Comment: note that wordpress & the theme are updated to their latest versions, but this error came up today when wordpress automatically updated to 6.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. The file ./wp-content/themes/tonda/framework/modules/blog/shortcodes/shortcodes-functions.php is calling a non exist function called tonda_core_is_theme_registered(). Look for line 8 in that file and comment it or look for that function o backups files.

Comment: I managed to figure out a short while after posting the question. I don't have much background in coding so the error stressed me out! Thank you for your response